# x86 assembly: How does the 'subl' command work in AT&T syntax

Tags: assembly, x86, att

`%edx` has a value of `0x3`, and `%eax` has a value of `0x100`.
Then we have the instruction: `subl %edx, %eax`
What's the result value of `%eax`?

Comment: You could always look at an [instruction set reference](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SUB.html) . Although the instruction set reference is for Intel ordering (dest, src) you can still use the instruction set references by swapping the operands (src,dest) when reading it. Alternatively you can load up your assembler code in a debugger like _GDB_ and use `layout asm` and you can step through the instructions to see the result and the flags.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have

```
movl $3, %edx
movl $0x100, %eax
```

as input values. The instruction

```
subl %edx, %eax
```

just subtracts 3(dec) in EDX from 100(hex) in EAX resulting in 100h-3h=`0FDh`.

Comment: and where is the result stored?

Comment: The result is stored in `%eax`.